# is it haram to work at a company where they produce alcohol but not actually sell it myself?

Tags: halal-haram

I have been looking to find a good job for quite some time now, I finally managed to get an interview at the M&S cafe as a waitress, but the M&S COMPANY sells alcohol. even though I will not be selling or working or TOUCHING the alcohol, is it still haram/forbidden for me to work there? I understand some people will see this as being haram but bare in mind that I live in the united kingdom where it is extremely hard to find a Halal shop or restaurant, although, most Halal restaurants here sell alcohol.
thanks.